# How to make custom TabBar active to center of the screen in scroll view using react native?

Tags: react-native

**I wanna make my active tabBar to be center the screen.**

Comment: Please, fix errors `/module:/App.js: Unexpected token (136:6)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here code full customize tabBar.
https://github.com/Heanphearak/react-native-deploy/blob/main/App.js